# CSS is behaving differently on Firefox (version 96 and older) than it is on Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

I know it's a topic that been discussed extensively but I've struggled to find the appopiate guidance for my use case when it comes to how Firefox is rendering elements with `::before` and `::after`

I've seen suggestions of using `-moz-appearance: initial;` but that was to no avail - my input doesn't contain other elements so it surely goes against the usual argument of an input not supporting child elements?

any workaround advice would be really helpful

EDIT: after some helpful comments pointing out that it wasn't an issue for some users, I updated my Firefox from 96 > 97 and it now also works for me, but I'd still be keen to address this potential "legacy" issue for users who may not be using the most up to date Firefox?

on Chrome:

[image]

on Firefox:

[image]

```css
.outter-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
 line-height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}


.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.label:before {
  display: block;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.label:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter-wrapper">  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2"        type="checkbox">
    <label class="label" for="checkbox2">
      <div class="label-wrapper">
        Only works in Chrome
      </div>  
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [It seems to work for me](https://postimg.cc/xcQtJRX5) in Firefox 99 (nightly).

Comment: same here! working fine for me too

Comment: that's interesting, I'm on 96. I'd imagine a lot of users aren't necessarily using the latest. thank you though!

Comment: I just checked, and it works fine in 97 as well. Is the code you posted broken for you? Maybe some other CSS on the "real" page is messing it up...

Comment: I just updated the post to say that when I updated to 97, it worked for me too (in production as well as my snippet) - so trying to isolate what may have changed between those two versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v96 `::before` and `::after` are not being considered in the flex layout on the label.
We can achieve the same results without the flax layout:

```css
.outter-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 12px;
  flex: 1;
}

.label::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.label::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.label::after {
  background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input class="input" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
    <label class="label" for="checkbox2">
        <div class="label-wrapper">
          Only works in Chrome
        </div>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, any reason as to why this is the case in v96 & < ?

Comment: There is nothing about this in release notes for v97. I searched on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) but couldn't find related bug. 

Comment: that was my confusion, couldn't see any mention of a related change! but thanks a lot for your answer 